# How to connect flexible PVC tubing to PVC pipe with no chance of connection breaking?

Tags: water, pvc, connectors

I am assembling the plumbing for a pond. I've put nearly all of the plumbing under water, so if something breaks, the leak will occur underwater, within the pond, and thus, it has no chance of the leak causing water to go anywhere it should not be...the pond liner is also 1/4" thick rubber with little chance of breaking.

There is one point of failure though: a place where some [2" corrugated, flexible PVC tubing](https://www.homedepot.com/p/HYDROMAXX-2-in-Dia-x-100-ft-UL-Sizing-Black-Non-Kink-Corrugated-Flexible-PVC-Pond-Tubing-1202200100/310812632) connects to a vertically-positioned [schedule 40 2" PVC pipe](https://www.homedepot.com/p/VPC-2-in-x-24-in-PVC-Sch-40-DWV-Pipe-2202/202300507). This connection gets 4000 gallons of water running through it, so a break would be very bad (i.e. flooding the neighborhood).

```
| | <-- opening of pvc pipe
| |                                                             \ <-- end of 80 ft long 2" flexible tubing
| | <-- 2" pvc pipe, sticks up about 5" above rocks            \/\
| |                                                             \/\
| |                                                              \/\
.......... <-- pipe is buried well in rocks in pond               \/ <-- other end connects to an underwater pump
```

What is a very very very reliable way to secure these two items?

- The flow of water at 4,000 gph means the water flow can throw the tubing around like when firemen let go of a fire hose.
- If need be, I can purchase a completely different kind of tubing. The tubing I bought was expensive, but insurance damage if the connection breaks would be far worse! I couldn't find any with threading.
- I planned to add an elbo joint at the top of the 2" pvc pipe, so the tubing can connect at a better angle, horizontally, but was concerned this additional joint just added another 2 points of potential failure.
- The vertical pipe travels 1.5 ft underground then comes to a T where it connects with a network of other horizontal pipes, so potentially something could be tied around those horizontal pipes, which will be buried under rock so can't go anywhere.

Comment: Why did you choose the flexible pipe instead of a rigid elbow and more rigid pipe? This seems a much more obvious solution, so there's likely something you haven't shared that led you to this decision. Sharing that will, possibly, eliminate the answers telling you to switch to rigid, _or_, could provide a solution that eliminates the concerns you had with rigid pipe in this location.

Comment: @FreeMan I considered this but was concerned this increased the number of connected parts, leading to potentially more opportunities for failure. It would need first an elbo, to point them horizontally, then two 2 ft pipes, then another elbo pointing down, and one more 2 ft pipes to get to the water.

Comment: You may be _shocked_ to learn how many glued PVC joints there are inside the walls of your house, safely guiding thousands of gallons water from here to there for years, nay, _decades_ without failure. So long as you properly clean, prime, and glue the joints, you shouldn't have _anything_ to worry about. TBH, I'd expect the flex pipe to have a greater likelihood of breaking than a glued joint in rigid pipe.

Comment: Oh, and rigid pipe and a few elbows should be _much_ cheaper than that roll of flexible pipe.